# How to change the id of a socket?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm making an app in node.js and I noticed that every time users open a new page or change page they get a different socket id. It is possible to change the id of that socket so the user has always the same socket id?
When the user connects to the server, it saves the uid and the id of the socket in mongodb and get that data each time he connects.

This is my code:

```
nspm.on('connection', function(socket) {
        db.c_oneusr(socket.decoded_token, function(err, docs){
            if(docs) {
                if(docs.ban=='1') {
                    nspm.to(socket.id).emit('ckusr', 'banned');
                    socket.disconnect();
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    nspm.to(socket.id).emit('ckusr', 'ok');
                    if (!docs.laston) {
                        docs.laston = 0;
                    }
                    initializeConnection(socket, docs.laston);
                }
            }
            else {
                nspm.to(socket.id).emit('ckusr', 'ok');
                initializeConnection(socket, 0);
            }
        });
    });

    function initializeConnection(socket, laston){
        var online = [];
        laston = new Date(laston);
        socket.uid = socket.decoded_token.uid;
        socket.buddies = socket.decoded_token.buddies;
        // id contains all ids of each user
        if (!id[socket.uid]) {
            id[socket.uid] = {};
        }
        id[socket.uid][socket.id] = 1;
        socket.join(socket.uid);
        for (var buddy in socket.buddies) {
            var buddy_id = socket.buddies[buddy];
            socket.join(buddy_id);
            if (uidlist[buddy_id]) {
                online.push(parseInt(buddy_id, 10));
            }
        }
        socket.emit('login', {
            online: online
        });
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.uid).emit('user joined', {
            uid: socket.uid
        });
        data = [];
        data["uid"] = socket.decoded_token.uid;
        data["id"] = socket.id;
        db.updpml(data); // Update user data
    }
```

Comment: You can use `session-id` instead `socket-id` or generate `GUID` on first connect, store to cookie and pass it to server on page change.

Comment: And how to do it?

Comment: Are you use sessions? What is your websocket library: `websocket.io`, `ws`, `sockjs` or smth-else?

Comment: I'm using socket.io

Comment: You want a socket.io session where you can set your own identifier in the session that will be the same for every new connection.  That will NOT be the `socket.id`.  That value belongs to socket.io and will be different for every new connection.  When you get a new connection, you can set the new and current socket.id into your own data structure for that user if you need to, though you have to realize that a user may have multiple active sockets at once (multiple tabs open).